# jsonlite suddenly retunring error: "Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Tags: r, jsonlite

Suddenly, over the weekend, my code is no longer working.

when I run it, I receive the following message:

Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer

the code is the following:

```
raiz      <- "https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/Expectativas/versao/v1/odata/"
tipo      <- "ExpectativaMercadoMensais?%24format=json&%24select="
indicador <- "Indicador,Data,DataReferencia,Mediana,numeroRespondentes"
restricao <- "&%24orderby=Data%20desc&%24filter=Indicador%20eq%20'IPCA'&%24top=10"

library("jsonlite")
jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0(raiz,tipo,indicador,restricao), simplifyVector = FALSE)
```

Comment: it is very strange, but it is working with rjson

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the `GET` function that jsonlite uses to read the website. Use `readLines` instead.

```
raiz      <- "https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/Expectativas/versao/v1/odata/"
tipo      <- "ExpectativaMercadoMensais?%24format=json&%24select="
indicador <- "Indicador,Data,DataReferencia,Mediana,numeroRespondentes"
restricao <- "&%24orderby=Data%20desc&%24filter=Indicador%20eq%20'IPCA'&%24top=10"

library("jsonlite")
web <- readLines(paste0(raiz,tipo,indicador,restricao), warn = FALSE)
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(web, simplifyVector = FALSE)
```

I didn't understand your query, but here we have one that works:

```
web <- readLines("https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/Expectativas/versao/v1/odata/ExpectativasMercadoInflacao12Meses?$format=json", warn = FALSE)
df <- fromJSON(web)
df$value
```